# WOW.js working on my local but not on my server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animate.css

I'm using wow.js for animations in my website with animate.css but when I test local here works perfectly but when I upload it to my server just not at all...
Here's my link to my website http://eloisemonteiro.hol.es/.

My js to call the wow.js

```
var wow = new WOW(
  {
    boxClass:     'wow',      
    animateClass: 'animated', 
    offset:       0,         
    mobile:       false        
  }
);
wow.init();
```

If you check the page 404 you will see that it works in there, here's the code of that one working:

```
<h1 id="fittext3"  class="wow bounceIn">ERROR 404</h1>
```

And here the other image not working on my index page:

```
    <div class="featurette" id="services">
        <img class="featurette-image img-responsive pull-left  wow bounceInLeft" src="img/customizacao.png" alt="Customizacao">
        <h2 class="featurette-heading">Customização de LMS</h2>
        <p class="lead">Customização da sua plataforma baseada na <mark>identidade visual</mark> de cada cliente com <mark>relatórios</mark> de acordo com cada necessidade.</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: I think you are calling WOW before the page / js files are complete loaded.

Comment: How do I fix this? If you check the site and go to the 404 error you will see that it works there... the only I can think of is the other images have a lot more classes, but in my mind that wouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Needed to call wow in some  setTimeout() because of my ajax page.